# How to authenticate with google account via ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you please help me ?

I am new in rails and i want to login with google using rails 3.2.8.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?view=asciicast

Watch Video and try

Answer (score 0):

download this app from here it is for facebook authentication using omniauth-facebook gem.you rather then use omniauth-google gem.generate key secret key for your app and necessary settings on google.

```
 https://github.com/kashiftufail/facebook_login_using_devise_and_omniauth_facebook
```

Hope you will do